# Get dependencies for multiple Angular projects in one place

Tags: angular, npm, angular-library

My company want me to get dependencies used by all projects in one place.
I think I will be able to do it with a library and adding libraries in dependencies and devDependencies of this lib.

e.g:

Project A --> Dependencies: `my-lib-depencencies: "1.0.0", "a-depencencies-not-on-all-project: "^2.0.0"`

Project B --> Dependencies: `my-lib-depencencies: "1.0.0", "another-depencency-not-on-all-project: "^3.0.0"`

etc...

My Lib Dependencies: `"@angular/common": "^17.0.0", angular/core": "^17.0.0"`

This means that the angular dependencies will be not declare as direct dependency of Projet A and Project B.

However I'm wondering if that's really a good idea (for example: when migrate the angular version I think it will be needed to add angular's dependencies temporary to each projects).

What do you think of that ?

Or do you know another way to do it ?